# Using env. variables as VM argument in launch configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, launch-configuration

I have a eclipse project which connects to different environments based on VM parameters passed in launch configuration.
In order to achieve this i have set env. variables in "launch configuration -> environment" and then tried to pass them as VM argument but i get an error as eclipse is not able to resolve those env. variable.

Any guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just pass the data as VM arguments directly? Why are you using Environment variables at all?

Comment: @E-Riz: that would mean changing 5 vm arguments and that leaves a chance of mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just below "VM arguments" window there is button called "Variables".
[image: Eclipse VM args]

When you click on variables it will give you an option to create new variable which can then be used in vm args as "${new_var}".

So probably we can't use env. variables as VM args in eclipse but this is a way out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same. it seems that after added,  it couldn't be removed? but I can edit it to avoid error:
new_var=-Dabc=xyz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `${env_var:yourenvvar}` in the VM parameter field.